# How do I keep Grunt from changing my files and edits?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator, grunt-wiredep

Grunt/Bower/Yeoman newbie.  Really frustrated and can't figure out what's going wrong.  Guessing this is a basic question.

In my HTMl, there's parts where my file has double entries for source files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/leaflet-dist/leaflet.css" />
```

I try to remove one of those, but then when I go `grunt server`, it changes the files to back how they were.

How can one make changes to their files and not have grunt go changing them back?  Something tells me this has to do with the wiredep task.  How the heck do I get that not to mess with my files?  What is going on here?

**Gruntfile below**.  Seems commenting out `wiredep` prevents this but this seems like a sloppy way to do this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json']
        //,
        //tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      options: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      },
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
          src: 'fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      //'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    //'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
}
```

Comment: Please post your gruntfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the `wiredep` task will find your project dependencies in your `bower.json` and inject the references to them inside the `index.html` based on the `main` attribute of each module you have installed and persisted inside the `bower.json` with `--save` option.

This feature of `Yeoman` is really usefull so you don't have to copy the scripts references each time you add or remove a component to your project.

There is actually an issue with the `Leaflet` library that prevent it to work with `Bower`. It's referenced at the bottom line of the [FAQ.md](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/250dabb3c973cf42c19fcde459ffa8ff808ec407/FAQ.md). You can also follow [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1354) or [the other related ones](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/search?q=bower&ref=cmdform&type=Issues).

So I advice you to remove the `Leaflet` dependency of your project for now and add the main files manually so the `wiredep` task will not mess with your `index.html`.